# tensorflow attention ocr on synth90k dataset

Tags: tensorflow, ocr

I want to evaluate attention ocr model available at http://download.tensorflow.org/models/attention_ocr_2017_05_17.tar.gz with Synth 90k test set. The problem is that evaluation yields very poor results, only 0.1 character precision is reported. It seems that for every input image model output is something related to FSNS dataset:

Here is a list of input and output values when running eval.py script with this command:

```
python eval.py --split_name test --train_log_dir attention_ocr_2017_05_17 --dataset_name synth90k --num_batches 10
```

- impeaching: Rue du Chauzou
- enticements: Rue le le le le le Tetuint lau...
- slinking: Rue de la Ruere
- ...

Here are some implementation details:

I have created tfrecord with 10 examples from Synth 90k test subset. Also, I have created charset_synth90k.txt file which contains character encodings (same content as fsns charset_size=134.txt).

This is my synth90k.py dataset file (including only changed lines):

> DEFAULT_DATASET_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**), 'synth90k')
>
> DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
>
> 'name':'synth90k',
>
> 'splits': {
>
> ```
>    'test': {
>        'size': 10,
>        'pattern': 'synth90k_test*.tfrecord'
>    }
> ```
>
> },
>
> 'charset_filename': 'charset_synth90k.txt',
>
> 'image_shape': (31, 200, 3),
>
> 'num_of_views':1,
>
> 'max_sequence_length': 37,
>
> 'null_code': 133,
>
> ...
>
> }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attention OCR model was trained only using FSNS train dataset and it will work only for images which look more or less similar to french street names. In order to apply it to images from a different distribution you need to retrain (or at least finetune) it using images from that distribution.